# How to deserialize 2 child elements without the container in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have the following xml and have a requirement to deserilize it

```
LockerBank xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ColumnList>
    <LockersColumn newPage="false">
      <LockersList>
        <LockerInfo>
          <Name>D08.001</Name>
          <Size>Medium</Size>
          <State>Available</State>
          <Terminal>false</Terminal>
        </LockerInfo>
        <LockerInfo>
          <Name>D08.002</Name>
          <Size>Medium</Size>
          <State>Available</State>
          <Terminal>false</Terminal>
        </LockerInfo>
        <LockerInfo>
          <Name>D08.003</Name>
          <Size>Medium</Size>
          <State>Available</State>
          <Terminal>false</Terminal>
        </LockerInfo>
      </LockersList>
      <Width>0</Width>
    </LockersColumn>
    <Section name="A">
      <LockersColumn newPage="false">
        <LockersList>
          <LockerInfo>
            <Name>D08.001</Name>
            <Size>Medium</Size>
            <State>Available</State>
            <Terminal>false</Terminal>
          </LockerInfo>
          <LockerInfo>
            <Name>D08.002</Name>
            <Size>Medium</Size>
            <State>Available</State>
            <Terminal>false</Terminal>
          </LockerInfo>
          <LockerInfo>
            <Name>D08.003</Name>
            <Size>Medium</Size>
            <State>Available</State>
            <Terminal>false</Terminal>
          </LockerInfo>
        </LockersList>
        <Width>0</Width>
      </LockersColumn>
      <LockersColumn newPage="false">
        <LockersList>
          <LockerInfo>
            <Name>D08.004</Name>
            <Size>Medium</Size>
            <State>Available</State>
            <Terminal>false</Terminal>
          </LockerInfo>
          <LockerInfo>
            <Name>D08.005</Name>
            <Size>Medium</Size>
            <State>Available</State>
            <Terminal>false</Terminal>
          </LockerInfo>
          <LockerInfo>
            <Name>D08.006</Name>
            <Size>Medium</Size>
            <State>Available</State>
            <Terminal>false</Terminal>
          </LockerInfo>
        </LockersList>
        <Width>0</Width>
      </LockersColumn>
    </Section>
</ColumnList>

</LockerBank>
```

I want to deserialise as follows

```
 [XmlRoot("LockerBank")]
public class TestBank
{
    public TestBank()
    {
        TerminalSize = 4;
    }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "ColumnList")]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(LockerColumnLayout), ElementName = "LockersColumn", IsNullable = true)]

    public List<LockerColumnLayout> Columns { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "ColumnList")]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(SectionLayout), ElementName = "Section", IsNullable = true)]
    public SectionLayout[] SectionCollection { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("TerminalSize")]
    public int TerminalSize { get; set; }
}
    public class SectionLayout
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(LockerColumnLayout), ElementName = "LockersColumn")]
    public LockerColumnLayout[] LockersColumn { get; set; }

}

public class LockerColumnLayout
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "LockersList"),
    XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(LockerLayout), ElementName = "LockerInfo")]
    public LockerLayout[] Lockers { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("newPage")]
    public bool NewPage { get; set; }
}

public class LockerLayout
{
    public LockerLayout()
    {
        ColumnSpan = LockerSize.U1;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public LockerSize Size { get; set; }

    public LockerSize ColumnSpan { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool IsTerminal
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Size == LockerSize.Terminal;
        }
    }

}
```

I get an error saying "{"The XML element 'ColumnList' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element."}"

How do i deserialize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ColumnList>` can contain multiple child elements of type `<LockersColumn>` and `<Section>` mixed together, so it needs to be deserialized as a polymorphic array of a shared base class -- in this case, `object`:

```
[XmlRoot("LockerBank")]
public class TestBank
{
    public TestBank()
    {
        TerminalSize = 4;
    }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "ColumnList")]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(LockerColumnLayout), ElementName = "LockersColumn", IsNullable = true)]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(SectionLayout), ElementName = "Section", IsNullable = true)]
    public List<object> LockerAndSectionLayouts { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<LockerColumnLayout> Columns { get { return (LockerAndSectionLayouts ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>()).OfType<LockerColumnLayout>(); } }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SectionLayout> SectionCollection { get { return (LockerAndSectionLayouts ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>()).OfType<SectionLayout>(); } }

    [XmlAttribute("TerminalSize")]
    public int TerminalSize { get; set; }
}
```

I added a couple of properties that returned filtered enumerables of each type of object in the list.